# How to append datatable to existing records in CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, datatable

I have CSV file `MyFile.csv`. It contains following data:

```
RollNumber  Name 
1           Amol
2           Ravi
```

Now I am fetching few records from SQL Server as follows:

```
RollNumber  Name
3           Viku
4           Vaibhav
```

I am not able to find a way to append these new records to existing CSV file. I don't want to repeat header again. I don't have MS Excel, just want to play with CSV. I tried using `Add-content`, but it didn't worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PowerShell v3 the [`Export-Csv`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx) cmdlet has an `-Append` parameter that allows appending to an existing CSV.

```
$data | Export-Csv 'MyFile.csv' -Append -NoType
```

On earlier versions you can work around that by [converting the data to CSV](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849878.aspx), skip the header line, then append to the output file using `Add-Content` or `Out-File -Append`:

```
$data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | select -Skip 1 | Add-Content 'MyFile.csv'
```

Comment: In addition I need to do few more things, like, I need to create new spreadsheet in same csv. how can i achieve that? Should I ask new question for this?

Comment: CSV is a text format, so you can't "create new spreadsheet in same CSV". And yes, you should probably post a new question (with more explanation as to what you actually mean by that).